# Diffculty in sending json array from ajax to view spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've consumed a json response from controller with ajax which looks like this:

controller:

```
@GetMapping("/articles/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<Article>  viewArticle(Map<String, Object> viewBag) {
    Iterable<Article> articles = articleRepository.findAll(); 
    for (Article article:articles) {
        articles1.add(article);
    }
    return articles1;
 }
@GetMapping("/articles/ajax")
    public String  viewArticlesAjax(Map<String, Object> viewBag) {

        return  "articles/list-ajax";

    }
```

articles.js looks like this

```
(function () {
if($('.page-articles-ajax').length > 0){
    console.log("Yea Im working",$.get);
    $.get( "/articles/json", function( data ) {
        console.log('got data',data);
        if(data && data.length){
            for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
                var article = data[i];
                console.log("article",article);
            }
        }
    });
}

})();
```

list-ajax.html looks like this:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:replace="~{fragments/layout :: layout (~{::body},'owners')}">

<body>

<h1>Articles</h1>
<div class="page-articles-ajax">



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

in articles/json ,the json array is returned ([here it is](http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c1b6bf73300005d007fd781)).I want to show the json response in a table format where the columns would be "title", "description" and "author". Being new to Spring and MVC I am facing difficulties.

Any help with this?

Comment: Can you maybe show the view code where you want to use the articles response?

Comment: @Rentius2407 added in the edit portion :)

Comment: @ProteetiProva Could you also explain what you are trying to achieve in layman's terms please?

Comment: @MinarMahmud with my novice knowledge I tried to simplify as much as I could. Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `jQuery` plug-in named [**`DataTables`**](https://datatables.net/). This is a stable tool which I have experience of using in production.

You need to do something like this:

```
<div class="page-articles-ajax">
    <table id="articleTable">
    </table>
</div>
```

And in `js`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#articleTable').DataTable({
        ajax: '/articles/json'
    });
});
```

`DataTables` is a highly customizable plug-in. See [it's ajax manual](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) for more.

If you don't want to use this plug-in, you need to build the table with `JavaScript` after you have the response data from backend. You can use `jQuery`'s strong API to achieve this easily.

***Suggestions & Notes:***

=> Change to

```
@GetMapping(value = "/articles/json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

=> `produce` and `consume` these terms are used from the perspective of API endpoint/backend.